# Oracle Procedure not a group by function error 00979

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

i have written this procedure to select employees from employee table and corresponding sum of total quantity sold by purchases table. my procedure is created without any error but the block is not working

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your code and your error here instead of links to images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query in your procedure to

```
SELECT e.NAME, SUM(p.QTY)
  INTO emp_name, total_qty
  FROM PURCHASES p
  INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES e
    ON e.EID = p.EID
  WHERE p.EID = empno
  GROUP BY e.NAME
```

Basically, use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`. If you're really dying to use `HAVING` you can use

```
SELECT p.EID, e.NAME, SUM(p.QTY)
  INTO emp_name, total_qty
  FROM PURCHASES p
  INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES e
    ON e.EID = p.EID
  GROUP BY p.EID, e.NAME
  HAVING p.EID = empno
```

To use `HAVING` the field it refers to must be in the results, and thus must be in the `GROUP BY`.

Best of luck.